# Format timesince filter to only show minutes - Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

Is there a way to format the `timesince` filter in Django to only output the value in minutes?

For example, `{{ comment.timestamp|timesince }}` displays `3 days, 4 hours`. I would like it to display `1680 minutes`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't be done without writing a custom filter.

Answer (score 1):

A shortened version of timesince. In my case only **years or months** needed.
This code should be in your appname/templatetags/custom_filters.py file, then you load it in template as `{% load custom_filters %}` and use the same way as timesince `{{ comment.timestamp|yearssince }}`
So, here is your custom_filters.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import datetime
from django import template
from django.utils.html import avoid_wrapping
from django.utils.timezone import is_aware, utc
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ungettext_lazy

register = template.Library()
TIMESINCE_CHUNKS = (
    (60 * 60 * 24 * 365, ungettext_lazy('%d year', '%d years')),
    (60 * 60 * 24 * 30, ungettext_lazy('%d month', '%d months')),
)
@register.filter
def yearssince(d, now=None):
    # Convert datetime.date to datetime.datetime for comparison.
    if not isinstance(d, datetime.datetime):
        d = datetime.datetime(d.year, d.month, d.day)
    if now and not isinstance(now, datetime.datetime):
        now = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)

    if not now:
        now = datetime.datetime.now(utc if is_aware(d) else None)

    delta = now - d
    # ignore microseconds
    since = delta.days * 24 * 60 * 60 + delta.seconds
    if since <= 0:
        # d is in the future compared to now, stop processing.
        return avoid_wrapping(ugettext('0 minutes'))
    for i, (seconds, name) in enumerate(TIMESINCE_CHUNKS):
        count = since // seconds
        if count != 0:
            break
    result = avoid_wrapping(name % count)

    return result
```

Comment: It's a good solution. A couple of things for folks to remember about custom filters: 1. include `__init__.py` in the template tags folder. 2. Restart the server when you make changes to custom tags

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do this with Django's built in [`timesince`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) filter. It has one optional argument which is a date to compare to, so it's not possible to specify the output format.

You could write your own [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that does this. You should be able to reuse a lot of the code in the [`timesince`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L801) filter and [`django.utils.timesince.timesince`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.8.4/django/utils/timesince.py#L19).